# Unscented Kalman Filter for Parameter Estimation (Tracking) of Amplitude Frequency and Phase of a Multi Component Harmonic Signal

Tags: python, estimation, kalman-filters, unscented-kalman-filter

I'm trying to implement an Unscented Kalman Filter that tracks the amplitude, frequency, and phase of a multi-component oscillatory signal.  Below is an attempt using the `filterpy` library in Python.  I've tried to generalize the process of creating the KF, but can't get it to work for a single component with no noise.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from filterpy.kalman import UnscentedKalmanFilter, MerweScaledSigmaPoints


def build_oscillation_kalman(n_components=2):
    
    dim_x = 3 * n_components
    F = np.array([[1,0,0],
                  [0,1,0],
                  [0,1,1]])
    F = np.kron(np.eye(n_components),F).astype(float)
    
    Q = np.array([[1,0,0],
                  [0,1,1],
                  [0,1,1]])
    Q = np.kron(np.eye(n_components),Q).astype(float)
    
    hx_a = np.arange(n_components) * 3
    hx_p = hx_a + 2
    
    
    def fx(x, dt):
        return F @ x
    
    def hx(x):
        amps = x[hx_a]
        phases = np.sin(x[hx_p])

        return np.array([amps.dot(phases)])
    
    
    sigmas = MerweScaledSigmaPoints(n=dim_x, alpha=.1, beta=2., kappa=-1)
    kf = UnscentedKalmanFilter(dim_x=dim_x, dim_z=1, dt=1, hx=hx, fx=fx, points=sigmas)
    kf.Q = Q
    
    return kf


def test_kalman():
    
    xs = np.arange(200)
    
    s1_phase = xs/30
    s2_phase = xs/12 + np.pi/2
    s3_phase = xs/4.5 + np.pi/4
    
    s1 = np.sin(s1_phase)
    s2 = np.sin(s2_phase)
    s3 = np.sin(s3_phase)
    
    phases = [s1_phase,s2_phase,s3_phase]
    components = [s1,s2,s3]
    n_components = 1
    
    use_noise = False
    
    if use_noise:
        x = np.random.normal(0,0.3,size=x.size)
    else:
        x = 0
    
    for i in range(n_components):
        x += components[i]
    
    
    all_reconstruct = None
    
    for i in range(1,n_components+1):
        recon_x = np.ones_like(x)[:,None]
        recon_x = np.concatenate((recon_x, np.zeros_like(recon_x)), axis=1)
        recon_x = np.concatenate((recon_x, phases[i-1][:,None]), axis=1)
        
        if all_reconstruct is None:
            all_reconstruct = recon_x
        else:
            all_reconstruct = np.concatenate((all_reconstruct, recon_x,), axis=1)
        
    
    kf = build_oscillation_kalman(n_components=n_components)
    full_preds = kf.batch_filter(x)[0]
    preds = np.array([kf.hx(s) for s in full_preds])
    reconstruct = np.array([kf.hx(s) for s in all_reconstruct])
    
    plt.plot(x)
    plt.plot(reconstruct)
    plt.plot(preds)
```

The above is based on the response by Royi here:  [Estimate and Track the Amplitude, Frequency and Phase of a Sine Signal Using a Kalman Filter](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/76443/estimate-and-track-the-amplitude-frequency-and-phase-of-a-sine-signal-using-a-k/76452?noredirect=1#comment178079_76452)

---

**UPDATE 2:**  *This part is an exact copy of a part of Royi's answer to describe the system for a single component EKF:*

Then the model can be:

$$ {a}_{k} \sin \left( {\omega}_{k} {t}_{k} + \psi \right) = {a}_{k} \sin \left( {\phi}_{k} \right) $$

With some math and pre processing of Kalman Filter you may derive the model with the matrices:

$$ \boldsymbol{x}_{k} = \begin{bmatrix} {a}_{k} \\ {\omega}_{k} \\ {\phi}_{k} \end{bmatrix}, F = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & \Delta t & 1 \end{bmatrix}, Q = \begin{bmatrix} \Delta t {\sigma}_{a}^{2} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \Delta t {\sigma}_{\omega}^{2} & \frac{ {\Delta t}^{2} {\sigma}_{\omega}^{2}}{2} \\ 0 & \frac{ {\Delta t}^{2} {\sigma}_{\omega}^{2}}{2} & \frac{ {\Delta t}^{3} {\sigma}_{\omega}^{2}}{3} \end{bmatrix} $$

Where $ {\sigma}_{a}^{2} $ is the process variance of the amplitude and $ {\sigma}_{\omega}^{2} $ is the variance of the process noise of instant angular frequency.

The measurement model is a bit more tricky. The measurement model is:

$$ {z}_{k} = h \left( \boldsymbol{x}_{k} \right) = {a}_{k} \sin \left( {\phi}_{k} \right) $$

Hence the Jacobian is given by $ \frac{\partial h \left( \boldsymbol{x}_{k} \right )}{\partial \boldsymbol{x}_{k}} = \left[ \sin \left( {\phi}_{k} \right), 0, {a}_{k} \cos \left( {\phi}_{k} \right) \right] $.

---

I'm a little unsure on how to generalize the Q array for multiple components, but I think the other elements are reasonably in line with the above solution.  I added an additional check on the `hx` function with the `reconstruct` array and that part appears to be correct since it matches the value of `x` where it only has the `s1` component.

What do I need to modify to get a reasonable output?

---

**UPDATE 1:** I was able to make this work as an Extended Kalman Filter.  I extended the `filterpy` class `ExtendedKalmanFilter` as `OscillatorEKF` and updated the `build_oscillation_kalman` function to allow Unscented and Extended implementations.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from filterpy.kalman import ExtendedKalmanFilter, UnscentedKalmanFilter, MerweScaledSigmaPoints

class OscillatorEKF(ExtendedKalmanFilter):
    
    def __init__(self, n_components, hx, hx_a, hx_p, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.n_components = n_components
        self.hx = hx
        self.hx_a = hx_a
        self.hx_p = hx_p
    
    def HJacobian_at(self, x):
        dA = np.sin(x[self.hx_p])
        dP = x[self.hx_a] * np.cos(x[self.hx_p])
        dW = np.zeros((self.n_components,1))            
        
        J = np.concatenate((dA,dW,dP), axis=1).flatten()[None,:]
        return J
    
    def batch_filter(self, zs):
        
        preds, xs = [], []
        
        for i, z in enumerate(zs):
            self.predict()
            preds.append(self.x)
            self.update(np.array([z]), self.HJacobian_at, self.hx)
            xs.append(self.x)
            
        xs = np.array(xs)
        preds = np.array(preds)
        return xs, preds


def build_oscillation_kalman(n_components=2, use_extended=False):
    
    dim_x = 3 * n_components
    F = np.array([[1,0,0],
                  [0,1,0],
                  [0,1,1]])
    F = np.kron(np.eye(n_components),F).astype(float)
    
    sig_a = 0.1
    sig_w = 0.2
    Q = np.array([[sig_a, 0,       0],
                  [0, sig_w,   sig_w/2],
                  [0, sig_w/2, sig_w/3]])
    Q = np.kron(np.eye(n_components),Q).astype(float)
    
    hx_a = np.arange(n_components) * 3
    hx_p = hx_a + 2
    
    
    if use_extended:
        
        def hx(x):
            amps = x[hx_a].T
            phases = np.sin(x[hx_p])
            
            return amps.dot(phases)
        
        kf = OscillatorEKF(n_components, hx, hx_a, hx_p, dim_x=dim_x, dim_z=1)
        kf.x = np.random.normal(0,1,kf.dim_x)[:,None]
        kf.F = F
        kf.R = 5
    else:
        def hx(x):
            amps = x[hx_a]
            phases = np.sin(x[hx_p])
            
            return np.array([amps.dot(phases)])
        
        def fx(x, dt):
            return F @ x
        
        sigmas = MerweScaledSigmaPoints(n=dim_x, alpha=.1, beta=2., kappa=0)
        kf = UnscentedKalmanFilter(dim_x=dim_x, dim_z=1, dt=1, hx=hx, fx=fx, points=sigmas)
        kf.dim_x = dim_x
    
    kf.Q = Q
    
    return kf
```

Also, I just updated the end of the `test_kalman` function.

```
kf = build_oscillation_kalman(n_components=n_components, use_extended=True)
full_preds = kf.batch_filter(x)[0]
preds = np.array([kf.hx(s) for s in full_preds]).flatten()
reconstruct = np.array([kf.hx(s) for s in all_reconstruct])

plt.plot(x)
# plt.plot(reconstruct)
plt.plot(preds)
plt.show()


amps = full_preds[:,0].flatten()
freqs = full_preds[:,1].flatten()
phases = full_preds[:,2].flatten()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, figsize=(12,3))
ax[0].plot(amps)
ax[0].set_title("Amplitude")
ax[1].plot(freqs)
ax[1].set_title("Frequncy")
ax[2].plot(phases)
ax[2].set_title("Phase")
```

Here are the results for one and two components with noise (reduced from the original noise of `0.3` to `0.1`):

[image: 1 Component]
[image: 2 Components]

Then for the single component version, here's the evolution of the state over time.  I guess the next obvious question is how to deal with the negative frequency at the end of the prediction.  Also, amplitude and frequency are negative, although that's probably not an issue.  Maybe a better strategy for initiating the state fixes that.

[image: State evolution]

I'm still very interested in making this work for the Unscented Kalman Filter since it sounds like it's a lot easier to customize.  The issue may be with the `hx` function since I had to separately implement it for the EKF.

For reference, here's the UKF result:

[image]

Comment: what's your model? 

Maybe reduce your model to a single sine wave. Make it work. Then add a second component?

Comment: When `n_components = 1` in the second function, the signal reduces to `s1`, which is a sine wave with no noise.  The `build_oscillation_kalman` then constructs a KF with state of size 3 (amplitude, frequency, and phase).  The state will always be of size $3N$ where $N$ is the number of components.  I was able to get a reasonable result using a more typical KF model with position and velocity, but the oscillatory version is not working.

Comment: Does it work with N=1?

Comment: No, it yields an erratic result.

Comment: Related paper [An Extended Kalman Filter Enhanced Hilbert Huang Transform in Oscillation Detection](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.04644).

Comment: @Royi - Any ideas on the UKF?  I'm just now getting back to looking at this and I can't figure out where it's going wrong.

Comment: Because you have not given your system model _in math_, your code is unclear.  However, even without knowing the math you're trying to implement, I can say that your $\mathbf Q$ matrix has absurdly low eigenvalues in the second case, and is singular in the first case.  The $\mathbf Q$ matrix is the **covariance**, and is your way of telling the filter how uncertain the values are.  With Q singular, you're telling the math that some linear combination of $x$ is _absolutely known_.  Since I don't see you introducing process noise, it looks like this will persist.

Comment: @TimWescott - I updated the question with a chunk from Royi's answer to the other question to describe the model.  Regarding the $Q$ matrix, it's the same for both the UKF and EKF, but only the latter works (using the second version of the $Q$ matrix).

Comment: @SuperCodeBrah, The model I built was to track a single frequency. When you add multiple signals it means the model doesn't match. Are you after the parameters of each component or are you after tracking the signal?