# Using kalman filter in R for sine wave frequency estimation

Tags: filter-design, kalman-filters, r

I'm pretty new to Kalman filtering techniques, and have a problem that I'm trying to solve.

Imagine in a lake I have a splash generator that sends out sine waves across the lake. At various places throughout the lake I have sensors that can measure the waves.  What I want to do is use the various sensors (maybe many) to estimate the frequency of the wave generator. Of course, each sensor will have a different phase lag and amplitude based on its position from the generator. I want to allow for the generator to be dynamic (frequency changing, etc).

I'd like to use a standard package like `dynr` in `R` if possible.

Then the measurement model part would be each sensor ($S_1, S_2, \cdots$):

$S_1 = A_1  \sin{( \theta \cdot n + \phi_1 )}$

$S_2 = A_2  \sin{( \theta \cdot n + \phi_2 )}$

$\cdots$

$\cdots$

This is what I see as the the latent variables (unobserved, but estimated):

$\theta_n = \theta_{n-1} + \text{noise term}$.

Then for the amplitudes and phase lags:

$A_{1_n} = A_{1_{n-1}} + \text{noise term}$

$\phi_{1_n} = \phi_{1_{n-1}} + \text{noise term}$

$\cdots$

$\cdots$

Would appreciate any guidance someone could offer.

Comment: Welcome to SE.SP!  There are a few related questions around (on this site). [This one is possibly the most relevant](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/84361/80).   The issue is that you'll need to use the **extended** Kalman filter because the system of equations you have is non-linear when it comes to the frequency tracking problem.  The thing you have in your favor is that the $\theta_n$ are all the same and not different for each $S$.  Unfortunately, I'm not sure how many R-o-holics there are here, so that might be a sticking point.

Comment: The extended Kalman will work -- in my experience (just once, but it was **impressive**), the unscented Kalman can acquire an arbitrary phase much faster than an extended.  If that's not important, then an extended Kalman will be much easier to implement.